# dotnet7 *.csproj not created in publish folder after command "dotnet publish"

Tags: asp.net, csproj

i try to run command `dotnet run --launch-profile myProfile` on ubuntu server, and i get  this error:

```
Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in /home/ubuntu/dotnet7proj/publish, or pass the path to the project using --project.
```

i search on the internet and i understand thet is because i dont have `*.csproj` file in my project.
in my developing enviromrant (e.g. the project before publishing) i do have the file, but after i run `dotnet publish` command, in the publish output directory, the file not generated.

how can i resolve it, and make that the file will be generated olso in the autput directory?

Comment: i added those line to the original csproj file, and is still not created.    `<GenerateProjectOutputOnPublish>true</GenerateProjectOutputOnPublish>
   <PublishSingleFile>false</PublishSingleFile>
   <GeneratePublishProfile>true</GeneratePublishProfile>`